# script with `read` in bash while loop causing high CPU usage when run as a systemd service

Tags: bash, read, events

I wrote a script to run specific actions conditional on input events informed by an event monitor, which looks something like

```
$ cat script.sh
-----------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/bash

stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor | while IFS= read LINE
do
    something with $LINE
done
```

When run as a script from a `bash` terminal, the script consumes a normal amount of CPU, and executes the action only when a new line is printed. However, when run as a service with the following setup

```
$ cat event.service
-----------------------------------------------------------
[Unit]
Description=Actions upon events

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The `event_monitor` command now takes over an entire logical core, and `strace` reveals that `read` is `read()`ing nothing as often as the processor allows:

```
$ strace -p $event_monitor_pid
-----------------------------------------------------------
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
................ad nauseum
```

while the service still registers events and executes the conditional commands when real events do occur. What went wrong here?

p.s. this happens with `cras_monitor` but not with `acpi_listen`. I tried to ensure that the `while` loop only starts after ensuring the underlying service successfully starts, but to no avail.

Update: here are some potentially relevant bits of `event_monitor`'s code:

```
...
#include <headers.h>
...
# Print to console function:
static void event_occurrence(void *context, int32_t attribute)
{
    printf("Some attribute has changed to %d.\n", attribute);
}
...
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct some_service_client *client # defined in headers
    int rc
...
# Some routine
...
    some_service_client_set_event_occurence_callback(client,event_occurence)
...
    rc = some_func(client)
...
    while (1) {
        int rc;
        char c;
        rc = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
        if (rc < 0 || c == 'q')
            return 0;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Isn't that simply starting the script as often as possible? I mean, if `stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor` has no output, won't the service simply restart immediately?

Comment: Is `$event_monitor_pid` the pid of `bash` or of `event-monitor`?

Comment: See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123). It rarely ever makes sense to call `read` without `-r`.

Comment: @terdon this behavior doesn't change if I add something like `sleep 30` before the while loop, so if the service is restarting immediately it would be at the loop without restarting the whole script. If that is indeed the case, it would also seem strange that when the script is run from a terminal shell it behaves as intended.

Comment: Well yes, when you launch it manually it isn't set up as a _service_. I admit I don't know much about this, so I may be completely wrong, but I understand that services are run constantly. And you don't have any code there to stop the service and not relaunch it so it looks like it is simply being constantly relaunched. I suspect what you want is to make your script an infinite loop so that it is launched _once_ as a service and isn't relaunched again unless it exits.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's a shorthand for the pseudocode, but yes, this behavior persists with or without `-r` option (among others, same goes for `stdbuf`). The PID is for `event-monitor`.

Comment: @terdon given that both `event_monitor` and `script.sh` retain their PIDs, I'm rather doubtful that the service is being relaunched.

Comment: That's... a good point.

Comment: So looks like that `event_monitor` whatever that is is trying to read from its stdin, possibly because it's an interactive tool and when running from systemd, obviously there's no user to interact with it, stdin is /dev/null and that tool fails to detect it's not  running interactively (and also fails to detect eof on its stdin which would be a bug). In any case, nothing to do with that bash script itself.

Comment: @seamux You may check whether `</dev/null stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor`, executed in an interactive shell, shows the same unexpected behavior of the systemd service.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you, that rules a couple things out. I'll update the question with `event_monitor`'s abbreviated code in C.

Comment: @fra-san `</dev/null stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor` executes in an interactive shell normally without the high CPU usage. After trying a few things out, it appears that, at least in GNOME, automatically starting the script (be it systemd, .profile/.bashrc, or ^F2, etc) would result in the abnormal behavior, so maybe it's due to certain `bash` option and/or environmental variable?

Comment: Oh the behavior is also present if started as a .desktop launcher. I've tried various combinations of exec and bash options to no avail.

Comment: @seamux which behaviour is present if started via `.desktop`, the problematic or the acceptable?

Comment: @roaima problematic

Comment: @fra-san d'oh! Must have done something wrong before, but when I tried again `</dev/null stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor` it DOES reproduce the high CPU usage.

Comment: @fra-san after playing around a bit,`2</dev/null stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor` behaves as expected, but it doesn't seem to make a difference for the script, and so far the only way I've found to daemonize the script without causing high CPU usage is to run it in a terminal shell. Also doesn't make a difference using `sh` instead of `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

It is your `event_monitor` program that is looping, using up all the CPU, not your bash script.

When run under systemd, STDIN has /dev/null attached (or perhaps it is even closed). When the event monitor loop in main does a `read(2)`, it is getting EOF, and going around the loop again.

When run interactively, event_monitor has the terminal attached to stdin, so the `read(2)` blocks until there is input.

event_monitor should only loop on reading stdin if it is open. If it receives EOF, it should either exit (probably not desirable in this case), or just sleep for a long time.

If you are unable to change `event_monitor`, you may have some success attaching a FIFO (named pipe) to stdin of the service. systemd has the `StandardInput` option (documented in the systemd.exec(5) man page), where you could specify `StandardInput=file:/run/event_monitor_ctl`. Then you just need to create the `/run/event_monitor_ctl` named pipe. For that, you can use systemd-tmpfiles by creating a config file (see tmpfiles.d(5)) to create that named pipe.

Comment: Thank you. Can I pipe or redirect my way out of this, short of programmatic fixes?

Comment: @seamux See edited answer

Comment: With `file:/run/event_monitor_ctl`, that would cause systemd to hang on the `open()` of that file unless you can convince  systemd to open it with O_RDWR. It may be preferable to use a wrapper script that starts `event_monitor <> fifo` or if on Linux (and `sh` is not ksh93) just run `sh -c ':|event_monitor<>/dev/fd/0'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wow, that worked, simple as that, just by changing `stdbuf -oL /usr/bin/event_monitor | while ...` to `stdbuf -oL sh -c ':|/usr/bin/event_monitor <> /dev/fd/0' | while ...`. Could you please post this as the answer and perhaps explain how it works? I had been trying wrapping it in `bash` with `0>&2 </dev/stdin` to no avail (works fine as a script even with `</dev/null` prepended, but exits right away as a service).